# Avoid duplications when trying to persist in 1-m relationship entites

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to avoid duplications when trying to persist however my logic in controller doesn't seem to be working if there is a brand name already set in `Brands` entity. So if I try to persist `Mercedes` as brand name then I get this error "The Brand already exists in database.". What it should do is to simply avoid persisting `brands` and just persist `cars` object with the `id` of `brands` entity. How can I solve this problem?

```
1 to Many (Brands to Cars)
```

**Note:** Option of removing `@UniqueEntity(fields="name", message = "The Brand already exists in database.")` is not viable because I'm using `brands` form type on its own somewhere else in my application.

[image]

**CONTROLLER**

```
$form = $this->createForm(new BothType(), null, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('both')));

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
{
    $brandsData = $form->get('brands')->getData();
    $carsData = $form->get('cars')->getData();

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:Brands');
    $brands = $repo->findByName($brandsData->getName());

    //If Brands doesn't exist yet
    if (! $brands)
    {
        $brands = new Brands();
        $brands->setName($brandsData->getName());
        $brands->setOrigin($brandsData->getOrigin());

        $cars = new Cars();
        $cars->setModel($carsData->getModel());
        $cars->setPrice($carsData->getPrice());
        $cars->setBrands($brands);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($brands);
        $em->persist($cars);
        $em->flush();
    }
    //If exists
    else
    {
        $cars = new Cars();
        $cars->setModel($carsData->getModel());
        $cars->setPrice($carsData->getPrice());
        $cars->setBrands($brands);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($cars);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return new Response('Brands ID:'. $brands->getId().'-Cars ID:'.$cars->getId());
}
```

**FORM TYPE**

```
class BothType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->add('brands', new BrandsType())
            ->add('cars', new CarsType())
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'))
            ;
    }
}
```

**BRANDS**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="brands", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"name"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message = "The Brand already exists in database.")
 */
class Brands
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cars", mappedBy="brands")
     */
    protected $cars;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; return $this; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }

    public function addCar(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Cars $cars)
    {
        $this->cars[] = $cars;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCar(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Cars $cars)
    {
        $this->cars->removeElement($cars);
    }

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }
}
```

**CARS**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cars")
 */
class Cars
{
    protected $id;
    protected $model;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands", inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $brands;

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function setModel($model) { $this->model = $model; return $this; }
    public function getModel() { return $this->model; }

    public function setBrands(\Car\BrandBundle\Entity\Brands $brands = null)
    {
        $this->brands = $brands;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getBrands()
    {
        return $this->brands;
    }
}
```

Comment: I read it and the manual however found it very confusing. Do you mind showing me where should I do the adjustments.

Comment: Can you show `findByName()`?

Comment: `$repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:Brands'); $brands = $repo->findByName($name); return ($brands) ? false : true;`

Comment: I mean show the definition of the function `$repo->findByName($name)`

Comment: It is a repo file: `namespace Car\BrandBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class BrandsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function checkNameUniqueness($name)
    {
        $repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:Brands');
        $brands = $repo->findByName($name);

        //If found then uniqueness check should fail
        return ($brands) ? false : true;
    }
}`

Comment: What would be the best is to able to call a repo in entity. I'm looking for it but couldn't find a way so far. If I can call a repo in entity then  I have a plan.

Comment: Problem solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472195/unable-to-persist-because-of-uniqueness-constraints-for-1-n) by bounding `BothType` to a new form model called `BothModel` rather than the entities.